# Open source war and ear files for testing

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, war, ear

I wanted to test some examples of WAR, EAR files for learning purpose. I am not having developing knowledge to develop application files. Can you give me where can i download different scenario of WAR , EAR application for my test purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat on its own is not capable of hosting Java Enterprise = EAR files. You would have to use TomEE for this (or Glassfish, Wildfly,...)

Here I found a sample WAR file for Tomcat:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/sample/

Here you can find a quick start for Glassfish detailing the deployment of a complete application:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0186/6nl8o25l3/index.html

Comment: Here's more: [CargoTracker](https://java.net/projects/cargotracker/downloads) (built for GlassFish, requires building from source with Maven); [Java EE 7 samples repository](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) (also requires building from source, instructions included)

Comment: @Mathis Can you give me the url for  applications to download and applications are able to connect to the database . For example petclinic kind of applications